# Subspaces of vector space V.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V$ is a vector space over field $K$ and it's sets $U$ and $W$ are it's subspaces that have the same dimension. Prove thet there is subspace $F$ such that $V=F \bigoplus U = F \bigoplus W$.

This problem seems simple at first, but i couldn't prove this statement. I think that i should use the fact that i know that dimensions of two known subspaces are the same, i just don't know how, any ideas?

Comment: Does that refer to  the sum of vector spaces or the tensor product?

Comment: Take a basis for the symmetric difference of $U$ and $W$ and then add a basis for a subspace $X$ such that $V = X \bigoplus (U + W)$.

Comment: But is $X\oplus U=V$ true @JohnCramerus ?

Comment: No, $X$ is not $F$. If $Z$ is the the direct sum of the complement of $U$ in $W$ and the complement of $W$ in $U$, and $X$ is a subspace such that $X \bigoplus (U+W) = V$, $Z+X = F$. However, my last comment was imprecise and might have implied $Z \bigoplus X = F$, which isn't necessarily true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $U$ and $W$ are not proper, then we are done. Assume that $U$ and $W$ are proper and consider $U\cup W$.

Case 1 : $U=W$. Then choose a basis $S_1$ for $U$ and a basis $S_2$ for $V$ such that $S_1 \subset S_2$. Take $F= \langle S_2-S_1\rangle$. Clearly $V=U\bigoplus F$.

Case 2: $U\neq W$. Then $U\cup W$ is not a vector space, thus $V\neq U\cup W$. Choose a vector $v\in V-(U\cup W)$. Let $F_1=\langle v\rangle$. Then $U\cap F_1 = W\cap F_1 = \{0\}$. If $U\bigoplus F_1 = V$, we are done. If not, proceed in this fashion ($U' = U\bigoplus F$ and $W' = W\bigoplus F$ and then you can get another vector $w$ and so you get $F_2 = \langle v,w\rangle$ and so on) until you get $V=U\bigoplus F_n=W\bigoplus F_n$.